# What are the possible causes for javac giving me an invalid flag error?

Tags: java, imagej, sci-java

I'm trying to compile a few java classes and they need external libraries.

I believe I have the right ones but I keep getting an invalid flag error if I plug in any of them other than one.

This is the command I'm running:

```
javac -d classdir -classpath "libraries\*.jar" -sourcepath src src\main\java\sc\fiji\cellCounter\*.java
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
error: invalid flag: libraries\scijava-common-2.83.3.jar
```

my libraries folder has just two .jar files at the moment, ij-1.53c.jar and the one in the error above. If I remove scijava from the folder and run the same command, it runs but says its missing
a bunch of packages that start with 'org.scijava'.

What could be causing the invalid flag error?
Any other help to get this to compile would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the library file itself is corrupted.  Can you get another copy or download it again?  Maybe from a different site?

Comment: Might need to build up the classpath or tweak the shell escaping to avoid the globbing.

Comment: @markspace If the jar was corrupted there would be a load error, not a flag error from `javac` itself.

Comment: Try explicitly listing the jars instead of `*jar`

Comment: Try listing them explicitly _separated by colon_ (on Windows; semicolon on Unix) (@D-Dᴙum) Also check `where javac` -- is it a stub in someplace like ProgramData or Common Files? I have sometimes had problems with the similar `java` stub messing up quoting, which could cause this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, strangely enough, removing the .jar after * solved the problem.